# Large amount alternative HTML for Flash?

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I have a flash video(swf) that i'd like to display on my homepage. But, for those without flash i'd like to display a html slider. how would i do this?
this is the code for the slider taht i'd like to display if flash isn't available

```
<div id="tab02" class="slider">
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><a HREF="images/slider1.jpg" class="fancybox"><img SRC="images/slider1.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
          <li><a HREF="images/slider1.jpg" class="fancybox"><img SRC="images/slider1.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
          <li><a HREF="images/slider1.jpg" class="fancybox"><img SRC="images/slider1.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
          <li><a HREF="images/slider1.jpg" class="fancybox"><img SRC="images/slider1.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
          <li><a HREF="images/slider1.jpg" class="fancybox"><img SRC="images/slider1.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
          <li><a HREF="images/slider1.jpg" class="fancybox"><img SRC="images/slider1.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var pauseWhenImageOpen = false;
    $(function(){
        $(".slider > div").easySlider({ numeric: true, auto:true });

        $("a.fancybox").fancybox({
            onStart     :   function() {
                pauseWhenImageOpen = true;
            },
            onCancel    :   function() {
                pauseWhenImageOpen = false; 
            },
            onComplete  :   function() {
                pauseWhenImageOpen = true;
            },
            onCleanup   :   function() {
                pauseWhenImageOpen = false; 
            },
            onClosed    :   function() {
                pauseWhenImageOpen = false; 
            }
        });

    })(jQuery);

    </script>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are already using jQuery, you can use the [jQuery version of SWFObject](http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/), it would replace the div slider with flash if flash is detected.

It sets a variable to true if flash is detected so can do:

```
if($.flash.available){
    //do flash
}  else {
   // start slider
}
```

SWFObject is also very reliable for cross browser embedding.